# showing error message-SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint v

Tags: php

I have developed a site and they are in the process of registration. In the Registration Form the userName field depending on primary key id and userName field will take an increment while insert data into database.The problem is that while multiple user try to register at a time. they are getting the same increment value in the registration form. so is there any way to make a queue in the process of registration to avoid these error message.

[image]

Increment method in the controller

next this load to view

[image]

after press submit button below controller function is loaded

[image]

Comment: Since you are incrementing and using existing in a form there is a chance that tow or more users get same value (userName) since you are using userName to be unique. You get this error

Comment: Try using triggers to manipulate such kind of values

Comment: Thanks For ur feedback..It Can be done by that way...